# Update SQL Database with JavaScript

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to update my database through a JS Function. After googling for a while I understood that it is clearly not possible without using AJAX.

So it is my first time and I tried, here is my JS code:

```
$("#update").click(function(event){
    var showArr = document.forms['ownForm'].elements['showArr'].value;

    $.ajax({
        url: './../pages/updateDatabase.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            showArr: showArr
        } ,
        success: function( msg ) {
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

and my PHP file:

```
<?php

try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=+++', '+++', '');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "UPDATE Users SET SHOWARR = true WHERE ID = 1";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    echo $stmt->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;

?>
```

But nothing happens! Where is my mistake?

Comment: Of course I removed credentials from the code and I pass a "showArr" variable, but I am not using it right now in the php file because I thought maybe this could be the mistake. In this case I just want to trigger the SQL Statement

Comment: If you just point your browser at the update page, does it work correctly.  It's a case of working out which part is failing - also calling the page directly is easier to show errors and work out how to bug fix it (although it only works if your using not using parameters).

Comment: Calling the PHP Page directly successfully updates the database! So it seems to be a problem with the AJAX Method I guess

Answer (score 1):

Your URL in ajax function does not look right:-

give the full URL like this

```
url:'http://yourdomain.com/page.php';
```

I hope it works